# Реалистичное освещение

Tags: unity3d, light

Как в unity 3d сделать так, чтобы свет шел из окна и при этом освещал все вокруг, а не только то на что светит?

[image]

Comment: Я понимаю, что интуитивно реальность намекает тебе, что это нужно делать так, но это СОВСЕМ не так. В видео играх свет постановочный! В супер красивых ААА играх, когда ты идёшь по коридору, где всего одна лампочка, художники по свету на самом деле расставляют 20-30 статических и динамических источников света.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiosity_(computer_graphics)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы понять, почему так происходит, стоит изучить особенности работы со светом в графике.

Есть три основных типа освещения:
Point Light, Spot Light и Directional Light.
Есть еще и Ambient Light, но он просто дает дополнительный свет ко всему, что есть на сцене.

Point Light - освещение от точки в определенном радиусе и интенсивностью. Имитирует свет от лампочки или например от раскаленного металла (т.е. мягкого освещения во все стороны)

Spot Light - прожектор. Свет идущий из одной точки в определенном направлении, углом и интенсивностью. Имитирует направленный источник света из точки, например фара автомобиля или фонарик.

Directional Light - глобальный направленный источник света. Чаще всего именно его свет образует тени и чаще всего его запекают, так как он является наиболее простым. Используется например для реализации света от солнца или луны.

Таким образом, то, как сделать свет в комнате от освещения из окна, тебе придется самому, исходя из перечисленных выше вариантов освещения.

Конечно есть еще одна вещь - raytracing. Он как раз таки просчитывает то самое отражение от пола на который попадает свет или например отражение света от освещенных объектов за окном, например дерева. Ведь в реальности свет в комнате не от прямых солнечных лучей, а от отражений от стен соседних домов, неба и т.п. Тема освещения довольно глубокая и для решения данной задачи рекомендую в начале со всем этим глубже ознакомиться.

Comment: Вообще, конкретно этот вопрос решается через Ambient Lighting.

Comment: Ну, это одно из решений. Все зависит от того, чего хочет он добиться.

Comment: В вопросе абсолютно прямо спрашивается, как получить Ambient Light. Raytracing, о котором вы упомянули, - это одно из решений. Простые источники света никаким образом не смогут создать что-то кроме обычного направленного света.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, если считаете ответ Ambient Light достаточным, то напишите его как свой ответ. К чему критика моего развернутого ответа? Я не вижу, чтобы я дал какой-то не верной или ведущей к заблуждению информации. Спорить на этот счет я не планирую, не вижу смысла просто тратить на это время.

Comment: Мое мнение - ваш ответ не отвечает на поставленный вопрос (разве что кроме лучей, но вы просто упомянули). Я свое мнение высказал, лучше было молча поставить минус и пойти дальше?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, учитывая ваши комментарии, достаточно было просто ответить отдельно. Не думаю что эти ответы как-то бы конфликтовали. Касательно минуса - ваше право.